# Twitter Fetcher - how to access data and parse into different structure

Tags: jquery, twitter

```
function handleTweets(tweets){
      var x = tweets.length;
      var n = 0;
      var element = document.getElementById('tweet');
      var html = '<div><ul class="nolist">';
      while(n < x) {
       // alert(tweets[n].data('scribe="element:name"'));
        html += '<li>' + tweets[n] + '</li>';
        n++;
      }
      html += '</ul></div>';
      element.innerHTML = html;
  }
```

[CodePen By Jason Mayes](http://codepen.io/jasonmayes/pen/Ioype)

Attempted to find data to parse so I could apply every item from data to be a bit differently structured. For example... icon, user, post date, image, interact.

Couldn't find how to access to data to be parsed. Help appreciated!